# C# Excel Interop set multiple cell Values at once

Tags: c#, excel, interop

How can I add values to 5 cells on the same row at once?

This is how add them right now:

```
ws.Cells[1, 1] = "1";
ws.Cells[1, 2] = "2";
ws.Cells[1, 3] = "3";
ws.Cells[1, 4] = "4";
ws.Cells[1, 5] = "5";
```

Expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a range and an array :

```
var rng = (Excel.Range)ws.Range[ws.Cells[1, 1], ws.Cells[1, 5]];
rng.Value = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // one dimensional array
```

Comment: That will not compile I think; your array initializer is creating a one dimensional array.

Comment: @Valip The array passed to `Range.Values` must be a two dimensioanl array, otherwise it will fail. Change the initializer to `{ { 1 }, { 2 }, etc. }`

Comment: It doesn't fail, just tested and works great defining 1D array

Comment: @Valip Good to know, I remembered incorrectly then.

Comment: @InBetween : Thx for pointing it out, I indeed forgot to get rid of the comma! ;)

Comment: @Valip : Thx for the edit suggestion! ;) Glad I could help!